# How to transform java class fields to an array of string values

Tags: java, arrays

I am looking for a clean and elegant way to transform an object variables into an array based on the variable values.

Example:

```
public class Subject {

    public Subject(boolean music, boolean food, boolean sport, boolean business, boolean art) {
        this.music = music;
        this.food = food;
        this.sport = sport;
        this.business = business;
        this.art = art;
    }

    private final Long id;
    private final boolean music;
    private final boolean food;
    private final boolean sport;
    private final boolean business;
    private final boolean art;

}
```

Based on the values of each field, I want to add the field name as a string into an array.

Example:
`new Subject(true, true, true, false, false)`

Expected result:
`["music", "food", "sport"]`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming no getters, you can use reflection:

```java
Subject subject = new Subject(true, true, true, false, false);

Field[] fields = Subject.class.getDeclaredFields();   // Get the object's fields
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
Object value;

for(Field field : fields) {                           // Iterate over the object's fields

    field.setAccessible(true);                        // Ignore the private modifier
    value = field.get(subject);                       // Get the value stored in the field

    if(value instanceof Boolean && (Boolean)value) {  // If this field contains a boolean object and the boolean is set to true
        result.add(field.getName());                  // Add the field name to the list
    }
}
System.out.println(result); // ["music", "food", "sport"]
```

[Working example](https://tio.run/##fVPJbtswED2XXzHwIZUKV@m5TgK46IICbnvIMciBFimVLkUaJOU0MPTt7nBIeYNdHzzkLG/ePA1XfMPfr8SfnerW1gVY4b3qg9LVuxk79mlu2srJRss6xFituffwgyuzZet@qVUNPvCAZmOVgA4DxWNwyrRPz8Bd60sIv5198fDlby3XQVkD291jv1whIPhs78HIF8jeIrheTuH4v@Haj6acMfZVSS2wQROtx/JcWhG9qpXhs8Sjk4IyfVHOAOD2Fr7JgHwkWEp/6zMCWygf7hLvB3DS93okNXeOv1L4AVHYr0R4w3UvkUhjXUEtEhB8zIAlbOH6D4l8D9LxgEQ20l1kxGIinSsvw7yupfdqqSWpQ@NchW6NdZJA105tYpfOCoVYjkCJO06XwFGrIn@Gq6hHwqViH7CDAGXIR0CJsGqKlKEMroWppW3gk7VacgM3N1Dkc0lJJFIk3CCMypNDbU3ALfLAYZkrkzbAjaB@oxtLfKRlaUvYyDZ9vooLUexH/Mk7WZSXBsT@cyEOc4DBVMJEj8bvTrgDG9jjqw@yq2wfKtTVBG2K1AphEeVp0vVe1ZMpTBprRbQ@vqPJ824Y8rsZ936b1MoPaNz7cS7Cme7HjGiHG2EerkvMNbgaBw93AYVlb6KkFT7Je/iwmO3FIS81wADZs1jsFpcDzVmEOmOI7FlspIHh8XiWwamWj5VDViAvaKMM17CwpgWV@56GTrT5X8KB@OX4EfvLCaf8L@fQGGzY/QM)

Answer (score 2):

For a general solution you can use reflection and Java Streams for this:

```
Subject subject = new Subject(true, true, true, false, false);
String[] trueFields = Arrays.stream(subject.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
        .filter(f -> {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                return f.getBoolean(subject);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .map(Field::getName)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

The result will be:

```
[music, food, sport]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use java's reflection to achieve this

```
 List<String> output =  new ArrayList<>();
    for(Field f:s.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if((f.getType().equals(boolean.class) || f.getType().equals(Boolean.class)) && f.getBoolean(s)) {
            output.add(f.getName());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(output);
```